# How to add a self reference in a recipe table to allow sub recipes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want a table récipes that contains a list of ingredients but also a list of sub recipes, for example:

```
#recipe yellow lemon juice
Ingredient         unit cost  quantity
1.Yellow lemon       Kg    1.7  1
2.--suppose it has ingredient 2
3.--suppose it has ingredient 3

#recipe mayonnaise
Ingredient                  unit cost  quantity
1.olive oil                 Lt  $2.5    1   
2.egg                       Kg  $2.5    0.12    
3.mustard                   Kg  $1.59   0.01    
4.salt                      Kg  $.9     0.01    
5.RECIPE yellow lemon juice Lt  $1.9   1 ------------this one is a recipe
```

How Can I tell that mayonnaise recipe uses yellow lemon juice recipe?
I have following, but dont know how to allow sub récipes in recipe table

Now it could be the case that I have 3 recipes `A,B,C` and recipe `A` has several ingredients but also includes recipes `B` and `C`

[here is fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7XvgmoUw8898yaau2VYoZ4/0)

```
Create table recipe
(
    recipe_id int primary key,
    recipe_name varchar(30)
); 
Create table ingredient
(
    ingredient_id int primary key,
    ingredient_name varchar(30),
    ingredient_cost float
);
Create table food_ingredient
(
    fk_recipe int not null,
    fk_ingredient int not null,
    measure float,
    unit_of_measurement varchar(30)
);
INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES 
(1,'olive oil',2.5),
(2,'egg',2.5),
(3,'mustard',1.59),
(4,'salt',0.9),
(5,'lemon ingredient 1',1.9),
(6,'lemon ingredient 2',1.9),
(7,'lemon ingredient 3',1.9);


INSERT INTO recipe VALUES
(100,'Recipe lemon juice'),
(200,'Recipe MAYONNAIse');

INSERT INTO food_ingredient VALUES 
(100,5,1.0,'Lt'),
(100,6,1.0,'Lt'),
(100,7,1.0,'Lt'),
(200,1,0.2,'Lt'),   
(200,2,0.5,'Kg'),  
(200,3,0.5,'Kg'),   
(200,4,0.2,'Kg'),
(200,5,1,'Lt');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a :

```
   Create table dressing
(
    dressing_id int, 
    recipe_id int,
    constraint pk_dressing primary key (dressing_id, recipe_id),
    constraint fk_recipe foreign key (recipe_id) references recipe(recipe_id),
    constraint fk_dressing foreign key (dressing_id) references recipe(recipe_id)
);
```

And I'd also add some sugar and vinegar to my mayonnaise... :)

Comment: So lets say dressing Will be the main table, and their rows Will be populated by recipes, so in this case I would have two rows lemon juice recipe and poisonous mayonnaise, is it correct?

Comment: Not at all. You fill your recipe as always in the recipes table. But when a recipe needs another recipe, you fill the dressing table with the mayonaise recipe (which must be in the recipe table). Recipes and SQL are confusing lol